# How to fix limit 16 connect adb

Tags: android, adb

I have set ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_MAX_PORT = 200 and reset the machine on the machine's variable also but when I do adb devices I get an empty list how to fix?

I want the adb devices list to show more than 16 connections help me fix

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the below code you can see that you have to specify the max port number instead of the number of devices.

Unfortunately I have difficulties getting it to work my self (again), I managed once last week but now fail (as allways) to get it working again....?!

```
    static int adb_local_transport_max_port = DEFAULT_ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_PORT + 16 * 2 - 1;
    
    static void adb_local_transport_max_port_env_override() {
        const char* env_max_s = getenv("ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_MAX_PORT");
        if (env_max_s != nullptr) {
            size_t env_max;
            if (ParseUint(&env_max, env_max_s, nullptr) && env_max < 65536) {
                // < DEFAULT_ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_PORT harmlessly mimics ADB_EMU=0
                adb_local_transport_max_port = env_max;
                D("transport: ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_MAX_PORT read as %d", adb_local_transport_max_port);
            } else {
                D("transport: ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_MAX_PORT '%s' invalid or >= 65536, so ignored",
                  env_max_s);
            }
      }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).